# Is it not possible to change an aws api gateway path and source_arn?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

While working on a project managed by terraform, I have tried changing the path to an endpoint, and it gave me the following error while deploying

```
│ Error: Provider produced inconsistent final plan
│ 
│ When expanding the plan for
│ aws_lambda_permission.lambdaApiGetStockPermission to include new values
│ learned so far during apply, provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"
│ produced an invalid new value for .source_arn: was
│ cty.StringVal("arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-3:<account-id>:<api-id>/*/POST/stock"),
│ but now
│ cty.StringVal("arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-3:<account-id>:<api-id>/*/POST/stockDispoOfArticle").
│ 
│ This is a bug in the provider, which should be reported in the provider's
│ own issue tracker.
```

Subsequent deployment attemps provided the following error messages:

```
│ Error: Error creating API Gateway Deployment: BadRequestException: No integration defined for method
│ 
│   with aws_api_gateway_deployment.ApiDeployment,
│   on api.tf line 50, in resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "ApiDeployment":
│   50: resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "ApiDeployment" {
```

None of those errors are seen when I launch `terraform plan` locally, and those errors are seen in out gitlab-ci executions

This is how we define the following resources

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "ApiDeployment" {
  depends_on = [
    ...
    aws_api_gateway_integration.lambdaApiGetStock,
    ...
  ]

  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.Api.id
  stage_name  = "latest"

  variables     = {
      deployed_at = timestamp()
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambdaApiGetStock" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.Api.id
  resource_id             = local.lambdaApiGetStockRouteParent
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.lambdaApiGetStock.http_method
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_function.lambdaApiGetStock.invoke_arn
  integration_http_method = "POST"
}
```

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "lambdaApiGetStock" {
  rest_api_id      = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.Api.id
  resource_id      = local.lambdaApiGetStockRouteParent
  http_method      = local.lambdaApiGetStockMethod
  api_key_required = false
  authorization = "CUSTOM"
  authorizer_id = aws_api_gateway_authorizer.ApiAuthorizer.id
}
```

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "lambdaApiGetStockPermission" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.lambdaApiGetStock.arn
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:execute-api:${var.region}:${var.aws_account_id}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.Api.id}/*/${aws_api_gateway_method.lambdaApiGetStock.http_method}${local.lambdaApiGetStockRoutePath}"
}
```

```
locals {
  ...
  lambdaApiGetStockMethod      = "POST"
  lambdaApiGetStockRouteParent = aws_api_gateway_resource.ApiResourceGetStock.id
  lambdaApiGetStockRoutePath   = aws_api_gateway_resource.ApiResourceGetStock.path
  ...
}
```

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "ApiResourceGetStock" {
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.Api.id
  parent_id     = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.Api.root_resource_id
  path_part     = "stockDispoOfArticle"
}
```

I do not have permissions to see anything in the API Gateway section of the AWS console

The endpoint that I have tried to change is still available at its old path

Below is the terraform version being used:

```
provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws" {
  version = "4.23.0"
  hashes = [
    "h1:JDJLmKK61GLw8gHQtCzmvlwPNZIu46/M5uBg/TDlBa0=",
    "zh:17adbedc9a80afc571a8de7b9bfccbe2359e2b3ce1fffd02b456d92248ec9294",
    "zh:23d8956b031d78466de82a3d2bbe8c76cc58482c931af311580b8eaef4e6a38f",
    "zh:343fe19e9a9f3021e26f4af68ff7f4828582070f986b6e5e5b23d89df5514643",
    "zh:6b8ff83d884b161939b90a18a4da43dd464c4b984f54b5f537b2870ce6bd94bc",
    "zh:7777d614d5e9d589ad5508eecf4c6d8f47d50fcbaf5d40fa7921064240a6b440",
    "zh:82f4578861a6fd0cde9a04a1926920bd72d993d524e5b34d7738d4eff3634c44",
    "zh:9b12af85486a96aedd8d7984b0ff811a4b42e3d88dad1a3fb4c0b580d04fa425",
    "zh:a08fefc153bbe0586389e814979cf7185c50fcddbb2082725991ed02742e7d1e",
    "zh:ae789c0e7cb777d98934387f8888090ccb2d8973ef10e5ece541e8b624e1fb00",
    "zh:b4608aab78b4dbb32c629595797107fc5a84d1b8f0682f183793d13837f0ecf0",
    "zh:ed2c791c2354764b565f9ba4be7fc845c619c1a32cefadd3154a5665b312ab00",
    "zh:f94ac0072a8545eebabf417bc0acbdc77c31c006ad8760834ee8ee5cdb64e743",
  ]
}
```

Was the fact of changing the path (and thus the source_arn) of the endpoint something that cannot be done? If not, what could be used as a workaround to make the changes available?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with `source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.Api.execution_arn}/*/*/*"` and work your way from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having someone who had the permissions to view the API Gateway interface on the AWS console check what is present, an old method using GET for the `lambdaApiGetStock` was still present in the console, and could not be deleted by terraform somehow

They had to delete the old unused method, and afterwards, subsequent deployments went smoothly